# AngularJS - Change Tracking

Tags: angularjs, settimeout, angularjs-timeout

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm looking at using the `$timeout` service. I've read that one of the reasons for using `$timeout` over the JavaScript `setTimeout` function is because changes to variables in the `$scope` don't get updated in the UI until `$scope.$apply` is called. While that's the word, I'm unable to confirm this with actual code. I've written the following:

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>AngularJS Count: {{total1}}</div>
    <br />

    <div>setTimeout Count: {{total2}}</div>
    <br />

    <button ng-click="start()">start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**myController.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
function myController($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.total1 = 0;
  $scope.total2 = 0;

  $scope.isStarted = false;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    if (!$scope.isStarted) {
      $scope.isStarted = true;

      $timeout(ngUpdate, 1000);      
      setTimeout(jsUpdate, 1000);
    }    
  };  

  function ngUpdate() {
      $scope.total1 = $scope.total1 + 1;
  }

  function jsUpdate() {
      $scope.total2 = $scope.total2 + 1;
  }
}
```

In this code sample, the changes to the variables on the `$scope` are updated in the UI. I'm trying to see a scenario, in code, where a change via the `setTimeout` function doesn't update the UI until `$scope.$apply` is called. Am I misunderstanding? Or was a change made to the AngularJS framework that makes the original assertion out-of-date.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong with my example. I am going to research it more and answer again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are calling `setTimeout` from inside `$scope.toggle`, this code is already executing in the context of a `$digest` cycle.  So, there is no need to call `$apply`.

`$timeout` will test if it is in a `$digest` and then only call `$apply` if it needs to.  This is very useful when building directives that bind to events that are happening outside of the angular context.

Here is a directive scenario when `$timeout` is needed:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {

    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {

            element.bind('click', function() {

                // $timeout is needed here because the 'click' event is outside angular
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm still not clear why setTimeout wouldn't work in "myDirective" though.

Comment: What are you unclear on?  `setTimeout` will work, But the angular `$watch` queue is only triggered by angular.  If you are making changes to scoped properties, and you are outside of angular, you need to tell angular to take another look.  If you haven't yet, check out [conceptual overview](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) and [Angular Is Slow](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/).